# Error al insertar multiples valores jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, checkbox

Quiero insertar múltiples valores en la base de datos, pero al momento de insertarlos, por algún extraño motivo solo se inserta el primer valor.

¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar una solución?

```
protected void InsertarConcentrado(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String ruta)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   
        String [] cmbRespuesta = request.getParameterValues("cmbRespuesta");
        
        for(int i=0; i<cmbRespuesta.length; i++)
    {
        Concentrado co = new Concentrado();
        Respuesta re = new Respuesta();
        Reunion r = new Reunion();
        re.setId_respuesta(Integer.parseInt(cmbRespuesta[i]));
        r.setId_reunion(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbReunion")));
        co.setRespuesta(re);
        co.setReunion(r);
        try {
            coDAO.InsertarConcentrado(co);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    dis = request.getRequestDispatcher(ruta);
    dis.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es coDAO?

Mi sugerencia sería que intentes hacer un insertMany en vez de muchos inserts, en especial si no tienes un poolConnection

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre hacerlo después de horas, aquí dejo la solución por si alguien llega a tener un problema similar. Prácticamente es el registro de respuestas múltiples en un cuestionario hacia la tabla de una base de datos llamada concentrado.
La parte del controlador es la siguiente:

```
protected void InsertarConcentrado(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String ruta)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    if(request.getParameter("btnSaa")!=null)
    {
        String [] respuestas = request.getParameterValues("cmbRespuesta");
        for(String respuesta:respuestas)
    {
        Concentrado co = new Concentrado();
        Respuesta re = new Respuesta();
        Reunion r = new Reunion();
        String idDAto = request.getParameter("txtID");
        re.setId_respuesta(Integer.parseInt(respuesta));
        r.setId_reunion(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbReunion")));
        co.setComentario(request.getParameter("txtComentario"));
        co.setRespuesta(re);
        co.setReunion(r);
        try {
        String msj = "";
        if (idDAto == null || idDAto.isEmpty()) {
            msj = cDAO.InsertarConcentrado(co);
        } else {
            co.setId_concentrado(Integer.parseInt(idDAto));
            msj = cDAO.ActualizarConcentrado(co);
        }
        String alert = "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert' "
                + "  <strong>"+msj+"!</strong>. "
                + "  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'> "
                + "    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span> "
                + "  </button> "
                + "</div>";
        request.setAttribute("mensaje", alert);
        request.setAttribute("baseM", cDAO.LlenarConcentrado());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
    
    
    dis = request.getRequestDispatcher(ruta);
    dis.forward(request, response);
}
```